Using Tokens from an Azure Container Registry as pull-secrets in Redhat Openshift
I don't seem to be able to generate a usable secret with Tokens in ACR. The method outlined here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/howto-use-acr-with-aro
only mentions the Access keys which doesn't allow me to scope permissions to just pull like the tokens allow.
when using this method to generate a secret with the token anyways I get unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information with an ImagePullBackoff.
looking at the microsoft article for access control for ACR, I see it mentions an authorized Identity.
Do I need to set up some sort of service principal in order for tokens to work?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli

Pull image
The ability to docker pull a non-quarantined image, or pull another supported artifact such as a Helm chart, from a registry. Requires authentication with the registry using the authorized identity.

Does anyone know of any resources that outline this process?
tried with:
simplified
echo '{"auths":{"registryname.azurecr.io":{"auth":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX="}}}'' | base64
copied to
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: scoped-acr-secret
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

I thought maybe it needed more details so I tried:
oc create secret docker-registry \
    --docker-server=registryname.azurecr.io \
    --docker-username=<registryname> \
    --docker-password=******** \
    --docker-email=unused \
    scoped-acr-secret

to no avail.

To use ACR tokens as pull secrets in OpenShift, the process is slightly different compared to using access keys or service principals.
You need to create a scope map that defines the permissions let's say pull only
az acr scope-map create --registry <ACR NAME> --name <SCOPE NAME> --repository <REPO NAME> content/read


Now, create a token that uses the scope map created above
az acr token create --name <TOKEN NAME> --registry <ACR NAME> --scope-map <SCOPE NAME>


Retrieve the username and password associated with the token
az acr token credential generate --name <TOKEN_NAME> --registry <ACR_NAME>


Done.  Successfully created the token and generated credentials. Now use this token as a pull secret in OpenShift, you'll need to use the username (which is pull-only-token) and one of the password values (let's use password1) to create the pull secret. You can follow the rest from the document you shared
oc create secret docker-registry scoped-acr-secret \
    --docker-server=arkoregistry.azurecr.io \
    --docker-username=pull-only-token \
    --docker-password="fUdzMu9x2GDK/DhZAIKNsazZmi5x9uO7JLrIktADJB+ACRBiaXnW" \
    --docker-email=arko@abcd.com

Link the Secret to the Default Service Account
oc secrets link default scoped-acr-secret --for=pull

